# gdb: отладка плагина

Tags: gdb, отладка, плагин

День добрый.

Есть некое приложение, которое при запуске подгружает плагины (под плагином имею в виду бинарный файл, в котором находится реализация нескольких классов; отдельно от приложения-родителя такой файл исполняться не может), вызывает пару описанных в этих плагинах функций и выгружает их из памяти.

**Вопрос**: можно ли при помощи отладчика gdb "присоединится" к такому плагину для отладки (т.е. присоединится перед тем, как будет исполнен какой-либо код в плагине)?

Есть, конечно, и решение "в лоб" - поставить прерывание в host-приложении непосредственно после того момента, как код плагина будет загружен, но еще не исполнен (но это приложение довольно объемное и искать в нем нужное место придется долго).
Придумал еще одно решение (которое и использую в данный момент) - запускаю приложение в отладчике, жду пока плагины загрузятся и завершаю работу. Затем ставлю точку останова на нужный метод (`bp "[NSColor blueColor]"`), снова запускаю приложение, останавливаюсь на breakpoint'e и запоминаю смещение для этой точки. Дальше уже либо вручную шагаю, либо высчитываю нужное смещение, исходя из найденного выше. Но это как-то некрасиво, должен быть другой способ, наверное.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если правильно понял, то приложение делает dlopen() на .so (.dll). А также вы хотите делать attach в gdb к уже запущенному приложению ?

Насколько понимаю, если приложенние уже сделало dlopen (к моменту Вашего attach), то br на код в плагине поставить можно, а иначе как ?
Ведь приложение должно **само** загружать плагин.

Comment: @avp, меня на момент создания вопроса заклинило на том, что плагин почему то != библиотека. Сам не знаю почему.
Вот второй способ, что я описал действительно мне подходит, но немного напрягает то, что смещения там получаются само собой другие, чем в ассемблерном листинге кода плагина. Я просто думал, что может есть возможность как-то к нему (плагину) подключится отдельно (опять же не учел, что и запускает его само приложение) и работать с "правильными" offset'ами.

Comment: @VioLet, хотя вопрос и закрыт, **но видимо можно**. Сейча опечатался в gdb и увидел :

    (gdb) br me_pro22
    Function "me_pro22" not defined.
    Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
    
    Breakpoint 1 (me_pro22) pending.
    (gdb)

Вот, видимо, и ответ для Вашего плагина.

Comment: @avp, да, можно поставить breakpoint на какую-либо функцию в плагине/библиотеке. Только у меня он (брейкпоинт) срабатывает только после повторного запуска программы (как я в вопросе и описал) - видимо потому что мой плагин это по сути _dynamically linked_ shared library.